# When resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I built a website in HTML and CSS, and whenever I resize the browser window (smaller) it messes with the components of the site, such as the navigation bar. The navigation bar is a series of images linked to their destination using `<img src=`. Any idea how to fix this annoying thing?

THe code for the navigation bar is below:

```
<br />
<div id="nav"> 
   <a href="/"><img src="Home.png" /></a> </a>
 <a href="/blog"><img src="=blog.png" /></a> </a>
 <a href="register.php"><img src="adopt.png" /></a> </a>
 <a href="user.php"><img src="useradmin.png" /></a> </a>
 <!-- <a href="login.php"><img src="\logout.png" /></a> </a> -->
 <a href ="places.php"><img src="map.png"/></a> </a>
  <a href ="login.php?logout"><img src="logout.png"/></a> </a>
 <!--- <a href ="login.php"><img src="q.png"/></a> </a> -->
</div>
```

THanks.

Comment: It's exceedingly difficult to know exactly what your problem is without looking at the code, can you post it, or at least the relevant part? Additionally, can you further explain what you mean by "...messes with the components of the site." What exactly is happening?

Comment: Code added. The navigation buttons are not staying in place. They move when you resize the browser's window.

Comment: A lot of things could be the cause here... what are the image tags in? a div? what is the style definition for that?  quick bandaid: put the navigation bar in a table, all in one row, so it doesn't wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give your menu container (`#nav`) a width in your stylesheet, like so:

```
#nav { 
width: 500px;
 }
```

This way, your menu will never shrink below the specified size, and the layout (of the menu in this case) will not break.

When that is said, you should also have *text* in your links, and use some [image replacement technique](http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/) to display the links as images/graphics.

You also have syntax-errors in your code; you close all anchor-elements twice.

Answer (score 0):

Set `min-width` on your container (or nav).

Answer (score 0):

Set a width on your `#nav` container that is equal to all the widths of your navigation buttons added up.  For instance:

```
#nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 150px;
}

#nav a img {
    width: 25px; /* 6 buttons at 25px = 150px total */
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<br /> 
<div id="nav">  
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr><td>
  <a href="/"><img src="Home.png" /></a>
</td><td>
  <a href="/blog"><img src="blog.png" /></a>
</td><td>
  <a href="register.php"><img src="adopt.png" /></a>
</td><td>
  <a href="user.php"><img src="useradmin.png" /></a>
</td><td>
  <a href="places.php"><img src="map.png"/></a>
</td><td>
  <a href="login.php?logout"><img src="logout.png"/></a>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no *rule*, but I dislike horrible practice that works against the development of the web. Using tables for layout completely ignores the most basic concept behind (X)HTML. The specification also says *Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content [...]*, so there sortof is a rule after all.

Comment: Tell me then... What is the negative impact of this one page using a table to lay out 6 images?  Let me answer that for you: There is none.      Works against the development of the web?  What the hell are you smoking?